# Write arraylist to a database java

Tags: java, database, jdbc, insert, arraylist

I have two arraylists to insert into 2 columns in a database table as follows:

```
arraylist1: 123444, 324555, 6423643, 532326
arraylist2: jkfdsl, nkjfsdlj, jdslkfjdlkj, jfsldjfsk, fjdlskjfs
```

I wrote the following code to insert the arraylists but it is not working.  I will appreciate your help.

```
try {
// Prepare a statement to insert a record

String sql = "INSERT INTO soundsdata.splog (arraylist1, arraylist2) VALUES(?,?)";
pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);

pstmt.setArray(1,sptospring);
pstmt.setString(2,eachList.toString());

// Insert the row
pstmt.executeUpdate();
}finally {
pstmt.close();
}
```

Comment: What types are those columns?

Comment: Let me get this straight: the entire content of `arraylist1` goes to one column and that of `arraylist2` goes to the second column? and the values would be stored in a comma-separated format? is that what you're looking for?

Comment: You can insert more than one record using ArrayList

Comment: Sujay, yes, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: So basically, you would create one row?

Comment: Sujay - Exactly.  Both arraylist1 and arraylist2 are on a row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's something that you can do:

*Assuming that you're trying to create one row, where the 1st `column` will contain the content of the first `ArrayList` in comma-separated format and the 2nd `column` will contain the content of the second`ArrayList`*

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
boolean processedFirst = false;
String firstParam = null, secondParam = null;

try{
    for(String record: arrayList1){
        if(processedFirst)
            buffer.append(",");
        buffer.append(record);
        processedFirst = true;
    }
    firstParam = buffer.toString();
}finally{
    buffer = null;
}
processedFirst = false;
buffer = new StringBuilder();
try{
    for(String record: arrayList2){
        if(processedFirst)
            buffer.append(",");
        buffer.append(record);
        processedFirst = true;
    }
    secondParam = buffer.toString();
}finally{
    buffer = null;
}
secondParam = buffer.toString();

String sql = "INSERT INTO soundsdata.splog (arraylist1, arraylist2) VALUES(?,?)";
try{
    psmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1,firstParam);
    pstmt.setString(2,secondParam);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}finally {
    pstmt.close();
}
```

Comment: @bdfios: Glad to help! Let me know if this has worked for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot store an ArrayList in a varchar column.

You need to store a string.

Comment: He's converting the list to a `String`.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to convert an arraylist to a string on the fly? I tried a cast and it din't work.

Comment: Or what datatype do you think I could change the column to so as to accept an arraylist?

Comment: @bdfios: What do you want the string to say? Most databases do not support array columns.

Comment: @Slaks, all I want to do is to store data in the form of "123444, 324555, 6423643, 532326" to each column.  As I described in my post, I already have the data in an arraylist, but since I could not write it as arraylist into the database, that is why I am looking for a workaround, hence my question, asking if it is possible to convert the arraylist to a string on the fly, so that I can then store the string in a database.

Answer (score 2):

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);            
for (Record record : arraylist1) {
    int index=1;                        
    ps.setString(index++,record.getItem());
    ps.setString(index++,record.getItem2());
    //
}
ps.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am a little confused about "Record record: arraylist1". Is Record a class library that I need to import? It is underlined as an error and I don't know how to handle the Record. BTW, I'm a newbie, thanks.

Comment: Record is an entity object of list generic type and record is item.eg. Book book

Comment: @MohammodHossain: what is the point of initializing `index` to 1 and then trying to `increment` it in the same loop? You would basically end up resetting the index to 1

Comment: for each loop will be continue on list size . after insert one record index will reinitialize

Comment: After insert one record index will be reinitialize and for each loop continue until list size 0

Comment: @MohammodHossain: It is generally a good idea to provide a workable code as an answer, or at least explain your steps. I for one don't understand where 1. `Record` is coming from (especially with context of the `ArrayList` question of the OP), 2. Where you're adding the `batch` even though you're calling `ps.executeBatch();`. Do you mind updating your answer and provide some better context to it?

Answer (score 0):

**Insert more than one record:**

```
public String saveOrder(ArrayList<KIT0053MBean> insertList){     
    System.out.println("SaveOrder DAO  Method is calling " +insertList.size());
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement ps2=null;
    try {
        con=open();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        con.getTransactionIsolation();
        ps2=con.prepareStatement(sql1);             
        Iterator<KIT0053MBean> it=insertList.iterator();            
        while(it.hasNext()){
            KIT0053MBean order=(KIT0053MBean)it.next();                 
            ps2.setString(1, model.getCustomerid());
            ps2.setString(2, model.getSerialid());                  
            ps2.addBatch();
        }               
        int i[]=ps2.executeBatch();
        System.out.println("###### insertion1### row   "+i.length);    
        con.commit();
        con.setAutoCommit(true);                
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {               
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());     
    }finally{
        close(con);         
        close(ps2);             
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you just paste a part of code that you had recently coded? Is there any specific reason of having `con.getTransactionIsolation();` over here? OP never had `KIT0053MBean` used anywhere either! I can find a lot of issues with your code over here, not to mention how much confused you would make the OP with this answer! I really don't understand your reasoning behind posting this answer, when you already have another one over here (which obviously you can edit)

Answer (score -2):

String[] stringArray = lists.toArray(new String[lists.size()]);

```
            String string1 = stringArray[0];
            String string2 = stringArray[1];
            String string3 = stringArray[2];
            String string4 = stringArray[3];
            String string5 = stringArray[4];
```

// then write query for insert into database

insert into tablename values(string1  ......)