# Android saving Arraylist data into database?

Tags: php, android, mysql, e-commerce

I have multiple rows of data in `sqlite` database and I want to save it as single row in `MySql` database on the server, as there are no available answers and I'm not able to make any algorithm for the same . Could anybody just help me out to make this algorithm or could guide me to any tutorials for it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127407/write-arraylist-to-a-database-java  may be it will  help you.

Comment: @ZezariyaNilesh i need to convert two columns as one single String in order to insert into online databse

Comment: you can use webservice to store your arraylist into database.